# Render time went up

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine

I made some new curtains for my scene today and then converted them to a mesh so nothing is being animated anymore.

[image: screenshot of the scene]

Before I did this my average render time for the scene was under a minute. Now it averages over 5 minutes. I didn't change any settings. What could have caused this? I made sure none of the objects have animations. I also tried deleting the new curtains but that didn't make any difference.

[Blend file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1msa3qmjfXDVCZRlRzR_dPaKy_YMtgp39/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: This file is crashing Cycles for me.

Comment: Hello and welcome. While files, images, and external videos or links may be helpful additions they should not be the only way to obtain information about your issue. Don't make understanding your question rely on downloading a file, watching a video or visiting an external site. Use the builtin tools to upload [images](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491) or [gifs](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963), along with thoroughly explaining the problem in written form so it can be indexed and searched for thus helping future visitors with similar issues.

Comment: I've added a screenshot of the scene with the wireframe overlay. The scene has almost 2 million vertices! The curtains have half of them and this black area at the front of the bed of 600k vertices. Not sure where are the remaining 400k. These high-poly objects are UV unwrapped. This results in heavy data and a big blend file (270 MB). You can use a *Decimate* modifier with Collapse and Ratio of 0.05 for each curtain to reduce the number of verts to 10%! The bed is more difficult because my Blender freezes if I try to use the modifier or Limited Dissolve.

Comment: About the render time, the rendered image has a size of 6000 x 3000 pixels! This is very large. Is this intended? Have you changed this or the percentage? You need very very powerful hardware to render such a large image in under a minute.

Comment: To fix the bed, go into edit mode, select 1 vertice of the black area and press L to select linked. In the popup at the left bottom of the screen limit the selection to *Seam*. Then the whole area is selected and you can delete these vertices. Fill the area with a single face. The blanket on the bed has a level 2 MultiRes modifier. If you bake a normal map from it you can delete it and save another 300k of vertices. I've disabled it here and the whole scene has now only 160k vertices, the file is 39 MB now. Hope that helps! https://i.stack.imgur.com/k8vOC.jpg

Comment: I'm glad you saw that. I had done a 360 panorama and was trying to get more detail to show friends on Facebook what I was working on. I changed the camera back to perspective but forgot to put the dimensions back. What is the normal pixel setting for that? Thanks.

Comment: The level 2 MultiRes modifier was from trying to bake the displacement map. It kept saying that I needed the modifier but kept giving the same warning after I added it. https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ybH7EtT_Nv9ikOvxQrH1PGwUyygS_P8N/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Don't I need the vertices in the dark area for the displacement map to show / work?